# use http-proxy inside a express JS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, http-proxy

I have get a login page code on the web based on express nodeJS.

I have many backend app running on different port. The goal is, when a user is authentificated in the nodeJS server, he's automaticaly redirected to his app.

But, if i can mount a http-proxy separated and run it properly, i would want to include proxying in this loggin JS code when user is connected.

There is the part of the code below.

```
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

(...)

// http://localhost:3000/auth
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
    // Capture the input fields
    let username = request.body.username;
    let password = request.body.password;
    // Ensure the input fields exists and are not empty
    if (username && password) {
        // Execute SQL query that'll select the account from the database based on the specified username and password
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
            // If there is an issue with the query, output the error
            if (error) throw error;
            // If the account exists
            if (results.length > 0) {
                // Authenticate the user
                request.session.loggedin = true;
                request.session.username = username;
                // Redirect to home page

                proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://127.0.0.1:1881' });

                //response.redirect('/home');
            } else {
                response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
            }           
            response.end();
        });
    } else {
        response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        response.end();
    }
});
app.listen(3000);
```

At the `response.redirect('/home');`i want to replace it by proxying, but nothing append.

I don't know if this is possible, because running 2 servers on the same instance.

Thank you for your help.

Regard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to use this package if you use express: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy

You can use it like this:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware, fixRequestBody, responseInterceptor } = require( 'http-proxy-middleware' );

const proxyMiddleware = createProxyMiddleware({
  target: 'foo',
  onProxyReq: fixRequestBody,
  logLevel: 'debug',
  changeOrigin: true,
  secure: false,
  xfwd: true,
  ws: true,
  hostRewrite: true,
  cookieDomainRewrite: true,
  headers: {
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
    "Accept": "*/*"
  },
});

app.use( '/youRoute/**', proxyMiddleware );
```

And then when you are loged in you redirect to you you proxified route :

```
res.redirect('/youRoute/');
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, i can proxying with your code. but it use http-proxy-middleware not express-http-proxy ? what is the differences ?

Comment: I don't know exactly the difference, but ``express-http-proxy `` is developped especially for express. And you say youare using express, so...

Comment: Ok thanks, but now, i don't know how can i do proxy redirect dynamically, that's to say, how to make a new route proxy for each user ? The app is always localhost but with différent port. I use a SQL database to get the user port, but it seems that the proxy has always only one active connection ... do you have idea ?

Comment: Routing users by port number is quite complicated and subject to security issue i guess. By doing this user id are predictable.

I think it's better to use a unique route and pass an alpha numeric id identifying the use which is not prédictable.

Comment: @Alaindeseine I am having the same issue...trying to redirect/proxy requests to different localhost ports dynamically. Did you ever find a way?

Comment: The first argument in the `proxy` function in `express-http-proxy` can be a function that dynamically returns the proxy location as shown in the documentation